Indefinite integral of li(x) dependant expression
I have the following $f(x)$ function:
$f(x)=\frac{4 (n-1)^x n^{1-x} \text{li}\left(1-\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^x\right)}{2 \text{li}\left(1-\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^x\right)-3}$
When I try to compute its indefinite definite integral in Mathematica, it fails due to the complexity of $li(x)$ part and outputs the following:
$4 \int \frac{(n-1)^x n^{1-x} \text{li}\left(1-\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^x\right)}{2 \text{li}\left(1-\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^x\right)-3} \, dx$
Is there any transformation I can make to the original $f(x)$ so that a program like Mathematica can compute the integral?
